# How do I call a partial view that expects a IEnumerable collection in a view that gets a model object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a version of WordPress in MVC4. Currently I am working on the page view.
I've decided that in this view I should also include a menu of all the other pages that have been created.
This is my method for the showPage view:

```
    public ActionResult showPage(string myTitle)
    {

            var query = from a in db.Pages
                        where a.title == myTitle
                        select a;

            PageModels item = new PageModels();
            item = query.FirstOrDefault<PageModels>();
            if (item != null)
            {
                return View(item);
            }
            else
            {
                item.content = "No page with title :" + myTitle + " found.";
                return View(item);
            }

    }
```

This is my method for the partial I am trying to render:

```
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View(db.Pages.ToList());
    }
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
@model Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Preview";
}

@Html.Partial("_ListPartial", new IEnumerable<Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels>)
<div class="content">@Html.Raw(Model.content)</div>
```

Finally this is my partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels>

<div class="dropdown">
@foreach (var page in Model)
{
    if(page.parent == 0)
    {
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => page.id)" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => page.title)" >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => page.title)
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => page.id)">
            @foreach (var child in Model)
            {       
                if (child.parent == page.id)
                {
                    <li><a class="child" href="/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => child.title)" >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => child.title)</a></li>
                }    
            }   
            </ul>    
        </div>
    }
}
</div>
```

I get the following error in my view:

```
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels>'
```

What should be the second argument of the @Html.Partial be?

Comment: You seem to be mixing things in your question. Do you intend to pass some object from your view to your partial view? If yes what those objects would be? Or you just want to call and render that partial from your view?

Comment: My full view receives a object, specifically the page with the title that matches the argument of the method. My partial view should receive all the pages and display them as a navigation menu.

Comment: Okay so the way I understand it, you don't need to pass some object from your full view to your partial view. That's why you showed us the `List` method. And that's where you want your partial view to come from?

Comment: Exactly, I don't want the partial view to get the same object. I want it to get all the objects of the class from the List method.

Comment: Okay see if my suggestion works for you.

Comment: You should do flowing two changes  public ActionResult List()
{
    return PartialView (db.Pages.ToList());
} and Html.Partial("_ListPartial")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view accepted a single instance of `PageModels`

```
@model Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Preview";
}
```

and yet you are passing that in your partial that accepts an `IEnumerable` and so you got that exception.

Now based on our conversation in your comments, you can load the partial using jquery:

```
<script>
$("#navmenu").load('@Url.Action("List")');
</script>
```

where you replace this code:

```
@Html.Partial("_ListPartial", new IEnumerable<Dynamic_Web_Pages.Models.PageModels>)
// with this
<div id="navmenu"></div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I do get a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdown' ... which is strange because my dropdowns seem to still be working. I've trying making it load the partial first and then calling the dropdown function but I get the same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. Where do you get that error exactly? Does debugging show you which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

remove new IEnumerable
and just keep  it as

Html.Partial("_ListPartial") in the view

Comment: I tried that and I still get an error saying that my partial is expecting a collection but is instead getting a model.

Answer (score -1):

So you should return PartialView instead of view  see below code

```
 public ActionResult List()
{
    return PartialView (db.Pages.ToList());
}
```